# GetElementsByTagName() не работает

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! В данном примере, пользователь выбирает радио-кнопку и нажимает на кнопку ОК. Если выбрана радио-кнопка `English`, будет выведена надпись

> Hello World!

Если `Russian`, то

> Привет Мир!

Но это почему-то не работает. Почему? Что я сделал не так?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input id="english" type="radio" name="language" value="english" checked="checked" />
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label for="english">English</label>
  <br />
  <input id="russian" type="radio" name="language" value="russian" />
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label for="russian">Russian</label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="button" type="button" name="perform">OK</button>
 </form>
 <p id="message"></p>
 <script>
  function funMessage() {
   var araLanguage=document.getElementsByTagName('language');
   var message=document.getElementById('message');
   for (var i=0; i<araLanguage.length; i++) {
    if (araLanguage[i].value=='english') {
     message.innerHTML='Hello World!';
    }
    else if (araLanguage[i].value=='russian') {
     message.innerHTML='Привет Мир!';
    }
   }
  }
  window.onload=function() {
   document.getElementById('button').onclick=funMessage;
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо всем, кто помог! Вот наиболее правильный вариант с исправленной логикой.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input id="number" type="text" />
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label>Enter a number</label>
  <input id="english" type="radio" name="language" value="english" checked="checked" />
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label for="english">English</label>
  <br />
  <input id="russian" type="radio" name="language" value="russian" />
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <label for="russian">Russian</label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="button" type="button" name="perform">OK</button>
 </form>
 <p id="message"></p>
 <script>
  function funMessage() {
   var araLanguage = document.getElementsByName('language');
   var message = document.getElementById('message');
   //перебираем массив радио-кнопок
   for (var i=0; i<araLanguage.length; i++) {
    //если радио-кнопка выбрана
    if(araLanguage[i].checked) {
     //если ее значение равно ...
     if (araLanguage[i].value == 'english') {
      message.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
     }
     //если ее значение равно ...
     else if (araLanguage[i].value == 'russian') {
      message.innerHTML = 'Привет Мир!';
     }
    }
   }
  }
  window.onload=function() {
   document.getElementById('button').onclick=funMessage;
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Anton121212, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Я так и сделал! Но код не отформатировался.

Comment: Теперь отформатировался. Странно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо этого:

```
var araLanguage=document.getElementsByTagName('language');
```

это:

```
var araLanguage=document.getElementsByName('language');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но попробуйте протестировать. Что будет выводить.

Comment: То есть? У меня все работает

Comment: Все время выводит Привет Мир! Не зависимо от того, какая радио-кнопка выбрана. У меня по видимому две ошибки. Первая, которую Вы указали и вторая, это сама логика. 
for (var i=0; i<araLanguage.length; i++) {
    if (araLanguage[i].value=='english') {
     message.innerHTML='Hello World!';
    }
    else if (araLanguage[i].value=='russian') {
     message.innerHTML='Привет Мир!';
    }
   }
Я уже догадываюсь, что здесь не так. Буду проверять.

Comment: @Anton121212, да, понял о чем вы. У вас нет проверки на то, какое из значение выбрано (чекнуто), поэтому выводятся по-порядку, заменяя предыдущее

Comment: Спасибо! Уже исправил. Полный правильный вариант написал в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MAzj6/

возможно так, маленькая коррекция - убрал checked из первого радио

в Вашем случае  var araLanguage=document.getElementsByTagName('language'); ищет тэг с неймом language

Comment: оно и с checked работает http://jsfiddle.net/MAzj6/1/

Comment: Ваша правда ))))